# win32 bind() to interface not working

Tags: c++, c, sockets, winapi, networking

Using Windows XP I'm binding a socket to a particular IP which should force the connection to use that interface instead of the default routing table.

Even though the bind returns no error the connection still uses the default route (in this case 10.5.0.2) instead of the bound interface (in this case 10.0.2.2).

Everything works fine on Win8 but XP just seems to ignore the bind.

I suspect it is something wrong with the routing table.. perhaps the metrics, but I cannot see what. Here is my test code which I'm running with the following args:

```
tcp.bind 10.0.2.15
```

This code connects to 50.57.66.64:25 and prints the server response which for this server is just the client's IP address that I'm using for testing which IF is actually being used.

```
int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"WSAStartup function failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    int handle = (int)socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // if they give us a bind port then bind
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in sa_loc;
        memset(&sa_loc, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        sa_loc.sin_family = PF_INET;
        sa_loc.sin_port = htons(0);
        sa_loc.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr((const char*)argv[1]);
        int bindResult = bind(handle, (struct sockaddr *)&sa_loc, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

        printf("Bind Result: %d\n", bindResult);
    }

    sockaddr_in clientService;
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("50.57.66.64");
    clientService.sin_port = htons(25);

    const int result = ::connect(handle, (SOCKADDR *)& clientService, sizeof (clientService));

    char data[1024];
    memset(data, 0x00, 1024);
    recv(handle, data, 1024, 0);

    printf(data);

    closesocket(handle);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my routing table:

```
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2       10.0.2.15       300
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.5.0.2        10.5.0.1       6
         10.0.2.0    255.255.255.0        10.0.2.15       10.0.2.15       20
        10.0.2.15  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       20
         10.5.0.0    255.255.255.0         10.5.0.1        10.5.0.1       30
         10.5.0.1  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       30
   10.255.255.255  255.255.255.255        10.0.2.15       10.0.2.15       20
   10.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         10.5.0.1        10.5.0.1       30
   46.165.236.206  255.255.255.255         10.0.2.2       10.0.2.15       5
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       1
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0        10.0.2.15       10.0.2.15       20
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         10.5.0.1        10.5.0.1       30
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255        10.0.2.15       10.0.2.15       1
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         10.5.0.1        10.5.0.1       1
Default Gateway:          10.5.0.2
```

Comment: Which route a packet goes more depends on its destination but its source. So it should not really matter from which interface it is sent. So if your code works, but packets travel the wrong way this definitly is about routing and therefore not a suitable question for SO, but might suit to Serverfault.com.

Comment: `argv[0]` contains the exe path+name, `argv[1]` contains `"tcp.bind"`, and `argv[2]` contains `"10.0.2.15"`. You are binding to `argv[1]` instead of `argv[2]`, so you are not actually binding the socket to the specified interface, and `bind()` fails but you are ignoring the error.

Comment: In this example argv[1] is the IP and bind is returning 0 (success)

Comment: Destination IP does not fall into local subnets which are 10.0.2.0/24 & 10.5.0.0/24 so it is perfectly normal that traffic is forwarded to default gateway. If there is multiple default gateways defined then it picks the one with lower metric (in multi-NIC config it is bad practice to have default gateway defined on both NIC's).

Comment: what about win7 and win10？ does it work on win10？